# Is there a DH/ECDH method I can use between NodeJS, CSharp and WebCrypto?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, webcrypto-api

I'm building lines of communication between browser extensions, a NodeJS application (server) and a C# application. I need to exchange keys between each instance using a method like Diffie-Hellman or ECDH so I can begin encrypting sensitive data.

The lines of communication are as follows:

**Browser** <--> **Node** <--> **CSharp**

*The browser needs to only communicate with Node, and the CSharp app also only needs to communicate with Node*.

I need to find a method of performing some kind of key exchange like ECDH that works in most browsers (can be browserified Node code) and has a compatible implementation on the NodeJS side. I need to find another method to do the same thing between NodeJS and C#.

I can see that there's a lot of examples in C# using ECDH (like this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2007/01/22/elliptic-curve-diffie-hellman/), but I can't see any mention of the ECDH curve like with Node. Is there some common way of performing key exchanges between these platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact WebCrypto does not supports DH - it was excluded from latest versions of standard. Thus the only option is ECDH.

As as example you could check [this link](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/tree/master/examples/How%20To%20Encrypt%20CMS%20via%20certificate). Also there is a "live example" of the same code [here](https://pkijs.org/examples/CMSEnvelopedExample.html). Please note that at the moment PKI.js is the only library working with WebCrypto and having all necessary for CMS encryption.

As for Node.js - you could use the same PKI.js library and any WebCrypto "shim" or "polifill".

As for C# - Microsoft Crypto API supports ECDH (in fact the support is via CNG, but it is not so important).

Comment: Thanks! The shims idea should work great. After further digging it seems as though CSharp has curve specification available for ECDH (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cngalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx), but how do I match them to the Node ones? For instance, I have ones like "ECDiffieHellmanP521" and "ECDiffieHellmanP384" on the C# side but no sign of something similar on the Node side, except perhaps "secp521r1" and "secp384r1"..

Comment: You can at least try those. That would seem correct.

Comment: I tried ECDiffieHellmanP256 on C# side and curve prime256v1 in javascript. while computing secret using public key from C# side, it throws errors.                                                                                               Error in event handler for (unknown): Error: Unknown point format
    at ShortCurve.decodePoint (background.js)
    at KeyPair._importPublic (background.js)
    at new KeyPair (background.js)
    at Function.fromPublic (background.js:34695:10)
    at EC.keyFromPublic (background.js:34473:18)
    at ECDH.computeSecret (background.js:31187:28)